# Plupload Image Upload preload images OR add images programmatically

Tags: php, image, dynamic, upload, plupload

I am using Plupload to allow users to upload images in a form. I am able to successfully upload images using Plupload. My program also allows users to save the form and continue editing/posting later. Now when the user resumes the form later I want to pre-load those files in Plupload from the server. I am not sure how to implement this.

I have been trying to implement addFile, but cannot implement. I would like to preload or add files to plupload programmatically.

Link:
[Add File Method](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Uploader#addFile-filefileName-method)
Your help would be appreciated!